# Connection between superfluidity and temperature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I don't understand the significance of temperature in relation to the presence of superfluidity. Why, in general, are low temperatures necessary?

Comment: Also note that Landau is really a necessary not sufficient condition and real superfluids normally have critical velocities (substantially) less than their Landau velocity.

Comment: @jacob1729 I was not aware of this, thank you. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superfluidity is a macroscopic quantum effect, and for the quantum nature of the single particles to emerge and dominate, their "effective range" has to spatially extend and become comparable to the interparticle spacing. Only in this way will the particles be "aware" of each other, and the constraints imposed by quantum statistics be enforced.

The "spatial extent" of a particle is quantified by its de Broglie wavelength, which goes as $$ \lambda \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m T}},$$ so it *increases* as temperature *decreases*.